# Getting only the rownames containing a specific character - R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, row, seurat

I have a Seurat R object. I would like to only select the data corresponding to a specific sample. Therefore, I want to get only the row names that contain a specific character. Example of my differences in row names: CTAAGCTT-1 and CGTAAAT-2. I want to differentiate based on 1 and 2. The code below shows what I already tried. But it just returns the total numbers of row. Not how many rows are matching the character.

```
length <- length(rownames(seuratObject@meta.data) %in% "1")
```

OR

```
length <- length(grepl("-1",rownames(seuratObj@meta.data)))
Idents(seuratObject, cells = 1:length)
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: you might want to use `grepl` or `grep`, `length(grep("1$", rownames(seuratObject@meta.data)))` OR `sum(grepl("1$", rownames(seuratObject@meta.data)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just missing `which()`

```
length(which(grepl("-1", rownames(seuratObject@meta.data))))
```